# Transforming Perspective in JavaScript – Matrix Math

Tags: javascript, c++, opencv, matrix, transform

I want to recreate the `perspectiveTransform` function from OpenCV in `JavaScript`. The reason I need to do this is because of [an issue encountered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054328/opencv-js-binding-issue-for-perspectivetransform-using-point2fvector-as-input). I found the actual `C++` implementation for this function [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matmul.dispatch.cpp) and `getPerspectiveTransform`, which seems to work completely differently [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp). They both seem to involve a mess of pointers I don't really understand, with no equivalent in `JavaScript` so I'm not sure how to write something similar.

I figured it's just some type of matrix math and surely there is a simple way to do it mathematically. If anyone knows anything about matrices / transformations like this I would hugely appreciate some advice / pseudo / code.

**Example data** I got from running a working version in `C++`

Input 1 (3x3) matrix

> [0.4709243769447963, -0.1089570231317744, 289.4386175367417;
>
> -0.05915378097999304, 0.3816064687798928, 503.5397702666958;
>
> -9.054861751225341e-05, -0.0001637295648326533, 1]

Input 2 (2x4) matrix

> [0, 0] [1000, 0] [1000, 740] [0, 740]

Desired output

> [289.439, 503.54] [836.068, 488.631] [862.289, 921.962] [237.598,
>   894.279]

**Details of the function**

[image]

**Where I am calling it in JavaScript**

```
var H = new cv.Mat();
H = cv.findHomographyEasy(obj, scene, cv.FM_RANSAC);

var obj_corners = new cv.Point2fVector();
obj_corners[0] = new cv.Point(0,0);
obj_corners[1] = new cv.Point(img1Raw.cols,0);
obj_corners[2] = new cv.Point(img1Raw.cols, img1Raw.rows);
obj_corners[3] = new cv.Point(0, img1Raw.rows);

var scene_corners = new cv.Point2fVector();
scene_corners[0] = new cv.Point(0,0);
scene_corners[1] = new cv.Point(0,0);
scene_corners[2] = new cv.Point(0,0);
scene_corners[3] = new cv.Point(0,0);

// NEED TO REMAKE THIS FUNCTION WHICH DOESN'T WORK IN OPENCV.js
cv.perspectiveTransformEasy(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);
```